# Selenium WebDriver: Firefox not getting element by tag name

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, headless-browser

I want to run Firefox headless using Selenium WebDriver in Python.

The point is to go to a page, wait till JavaScript is loaded, and collect all the links on this page.

To start testing, I did this code:

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

url = "http://localhost:3000/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
driver.get(url) 
time.sleep(5)

urls = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') 
print(urls)

driver.quit()
```

This always gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel.py", line 18, in <module>
    urls = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') 
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 545, in find_elements_by_tag_name
    return self.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 995, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/petra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/petra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 496, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

I tried removing this line `time.sleep(5)` cause I assumed it might be the problem.

Now `print(urls)` returns the following:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="27257d43-81ec-48e4-9ed2-55709a23d60f", element="e728d5ef-001f-4335-bd57-19a1f2d82683")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="27257d43-81ec-48e4-9ed2-55709a23d60f", element="2c59c828-8557-48cc-a79a-02ea3c9d2d65")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="27257d43-81ec-48e4-9ed2-55709a23d60f", element="e2058a00-9bad-4f0c-8e2d-a236a567dddd")>]
```

This output appears if I put `time.sleep(0)` till `time.sleep(4)`.

Either way, this is not the output I want; I want to see all the anchors on my page.

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


urls = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a")))

for url in urls:

    print(url.get_attribute("href"))

# Another example of printing URLs (where actual_urls is a list of anchors).
actual_urls = [url.get_attribute("href") for url in urls]
print(actual_urls)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is `ui` in this context?

Comment: Thanks! this worked, first I need to add references to `selenium.webdriver.support.ui ` , `selenium.webdriver.common.by` and `selenium.webdriver.support`